# Can't see entire SQL table in terminal

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am learning postgreSQL and created a table using mock data (from a random data generator). When I run the `SELECT * FROM {table}` command, I can only see the top part of the table. It seems to cut off at a certain point and then restart from the beginning. Is this a terminal setting or is there something else I am doing wrong?

Thank you for your help!

[image: screenshot of terminal output]

Comment: It's rather not needed to select all from table like you wanted here - it is unpractical but also may be costly in terms of db or network. If you wanna observe what happens use `limit`, if you want to know how many rows you have in whole table, or with some filtering, use `count`.

Comment: I downvote your question since you post personnal date in your link !!!! Please erase it and repost your question with not such data.

Comment: @Dri372 this is data from a mock data generator. It is not real data.

Comment: OK I remove my downvote :-)

Comment: What os ? What cmd line interpreter?

Comment: `psql` feeds large output to a pager.  Which one is determined by PAGER or PSQL_PAGER environment variables.  Your pager seems to be misbehaving somehow, but without knowing what pager you are using, it would be hard to give solutions.  Since the problem is with a system supplied tool, we would also need to know your OS and version.

Comment: I actually just got it figured out, for some reason my default was changed to bash instead of zsh. Now it is working where I can scroll and see the entire table. Thank you all!

Comment: Please make your own solution an answer, so other people with the same problem can find the solution easily.

Comment: @ErichKitzmueller Ok thank you, I will do that

Answer (score 0):

I actually just got it figured out, for some reason my default was changed to bash instead of zsh. Now it is working where I can scroll and see the entire table. Thank you all!